# I want to display 3 EditText values on single TextView

Tags: java, android, string

How can I display on the TextView tv, the concatenated values from the 3 edit texts, et1, et2, et3, after the click event on button b1?

I written this code....

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);

    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            String name,age,contact;

             name=et1.getText().toString();
            tv.setText(name);

            age=et2.getText().toString();
            tv.setText(age);

            contact=et3.getText().toString();
            tv.setText(contact);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you elaborate the question? Its not clear

Comment: tv.setText(name + age + contact);

Comment: try : tv.setText(name+age+contact);  after

Comment: Thank you Divyesh Patel.... It's working ✌

Comment: you can append data..like `tv.append("string")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){

        String name,age,contact;

         name=et1.getText().toString();
         age=et2.getText().toString();
         contact=et3.getText().toString();

        tv.setText(name + " "+ age + " "+contact);
    }
});
```

> output : Upendra 25 9876543210

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough, if I'm understanding your question.  Below I have revised your code to include a String named fullValue that will include all three values found in your edit text when you select your button.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);

    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            String name,age,contact,fullValue;

            name=et1.getText().toString();
            age=et2.getText().toString();
            contact=et3.getText().toString();
            fullValue = name + ", " + age + ", " + contact;
            tv.setText(fullValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution by [Divyesh Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6756514/divyesh-patel) given in comment to the question:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                String name,age,contact;

                 name=et1.getText().toString();
                age=et2.getText().toString();
                contact=et3.getText().toString();
                tv.setText(name+age+contact);
            }
        });
```